# How to make the thinnest font

Tags: html, css, fonts, photoshop

I have a font in photoshop:

[image: photoshop]

and when I set  `font-weight: 100` the result is too `bold`.

[image: result]

`Font-size:72px`, `font-family:"Montseratt"`

When I'm changing `font-weight` from `300` to `400` font also changings (for `font-weight:` `100, 200, 300` font the same). I guess it means that property works, but how can I make font thinner than value that property can set

Comment: Are you using Google font?

Comment: @patelarpan, yes

Comment: Can you add weight 100 when link Google font

Comment: I think the thinner weight is 100 : https://gist.github.com/christopheranderton/d67d26638a5f283a8e6887da307deb58

Comment: Like this <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @patelarpan do you mean to tell him that 100 his thinner??

Comment: I think he not include 100 when link Google font

Comment: 100 is normal font wieght

Comment: @Maks see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113523/how-to-set-super-thin-font-weight-less-than-100-in-css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170515/discussion-between-patelarpan-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this.

> you make a typo it's `font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;` not
>   `font-family:"Montseratt"`

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
}

.thin {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.normal {
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,400" rel="stylesheet">

<p class="thin">THIN<p>
<p class="normal">NORMAL</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p.normal {
    font-weight: normal;
}
p.thick {
font-weight: bold;
}
p.thicker {
 font-weight: 900;
}
```

it may  help you

Comment: its for reffrence so he may get any idea.

Comment: lollll look at his question he told he use `font-weight:100` and he want thinner